# Django rest framework. Разный вывод связанных полей в одном запросе

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Допустим имеются такие модели и сериализатор:

```py
class Article(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = '__all__'
```

Создаем статью с запросом `{'title': ['Название'], 'category': ['1']}`. В ответ возвращается строка вида: `{id: 1, title: 'Название', category: 1}`.

Вопрос: Как вывести весь объект категории, но при этом оставить запись с помощью ключа. В документации видел лишь примеры работы, либо только с ключами, либо только с объектами.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для объекта `Category` необходимо создать свой сериализатор который будет использоваться для представления `category` в `ArticleSerializer`
Для создания `article` используем `category_id`:

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = '__all__'


class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    title = serializers.CharField(max_length=255)
    category_id = serializers.IntegerField(write_only=True)
    category = CategorySerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'category_id', 'category')
```

Запрос на создание: {'title': ['Название'], 'category_id': ['1']}

Comment: Да, была такая идея. Но я думал есть более красивая реализация.